Can I study different degrees in two universities in China at the same time?
I have two master's degrees. One is from a Chinese university, and I am about to finish it, with only my thesis remaining. The other master's degree, which I have already completed, is from India. I have applied for and been accepted into a PhD program in China using my master's degree from India.
My question is: Is it legal to study both degrees simultaneously in China, specifically finishing my master's degree online (I am planning not to inform the university about my PhD program as I know I can finish my degree online), while starting my PhD at a different university, which will sponsor my visa?
If more details are required please let me know.
Thank you so much for your time and consideration.

I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with Travel.

It's either an academia or expats question.  Definitely not a Travel question.

Thank you so much for your time, I am really sorry for the inconvenience, if my question is not related to travel, I can close my question of course . Can you please guide me how to close the question.

Why do you need a second masters if you're a PhD student? What are you trying to achieve?
